# Best Ruby on Rails CMS for a project that is not related to generating websites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system

Just started learning Ruby on Rails here, and I'm about to start working on a backend for content management for custom-built mobile clients, where the clients connect to the server through a web-service.

I figured that instead of reinventing the wheel it would probably be best to just use a well-respected CMS gem to manage users and the various objects (products, product categories, images, etc), but every single one I look at seem to be almost exclusively made for generating websites, and not to manage content for a webservice.

Are there any good RoR CMS gems out there that I can tailor to fit my needs, or do I have to write my own from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) for your CMS application.

Comment: Oh that looks great. Also found Active Admin now. Seems looking at CMS gems was the wrong category for what I'm trying to do.